# ReactJS not working in codepen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, babeljs

```
const api_key ='09e33ec3a8beb8e071a993a59de37c17';

class WeatherApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      city: 'Dhaka',
      description: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.grabWeather(this.state.city);
  }

  grabWeather(city){
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${api_key}&q=${city}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      this.setState({description: json.weather[0].description})
    });
    console.log("working");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Today's Weather</h1>
        <h2>City: { this.state.city }</h2>
        <h2>Description: {this.state.description}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<WeatherApp />,
document.getElementById("app"));
```

I have added Babel as the pre-processor and added React and ReactDOM from the quick-add. I can see the output when I put it in jsbin but not in codepen. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with it?

Here is the [link](https://codepen.io/imranfarid/pen/GGEQrb?editors=1011).

Comment: is there something specific about codepen that you want to get running? what about https://codesandbox.io/ ? it was built with react in mind

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about codesandbox.io. It is going to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your fetch request is failing because you're trying to fetch data from website using HTTP on HTTPS website.

Just change the fetch URL from

`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${api_key}&q=${city}`

to

`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=${api_key}&q=${city}`